# XML function by value issue?

Tags: xml, powershell, call-by-value

I have a function that returns a hash table with a variety of keys, one of which is XML. I also have some code that is intended to revise this XML before returning it. However, I am having what at first appeared to be pipeline pollution issues, but I have isolated it to the XML replacement code.

So, initially I did all my XML replacement directly with the key in the return hash using `$result.xml`. However, I have since changed the code to use a separate variable like this:

```
$revisedXml = $result.xml
$oldnode = $revisedXml.selectSingleNode("/Definitions/InstallTypes/InstallType[@id='$supersedes']")
$newnode = $temp.xml.selectSingleNode("/Definitions/InstallTypes/InstallType[@id='$supersedes']")
$importNode = $revisedXml.ImportNode($newnode, $true)
$oldnode.ParentNode.AppendChild($importNode)
$oldnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild($oldnode)
```

However, either of those last two lines is what causes the `$return` hash to blow up. Which has me thinking I think I remember something about XML being by reference not by value, so what I am really doing is directly accessing the XML, just via a new pointer, and what I am changing somehow blows up the whole hash table variable that also references the XML. Does this sound right, or am I going down a wrong path already?

Also, and perhaps related. What I ultimately am looking to do is search for a specific node in `$result.xml` and in a different `$temp.xml` (loaded from different files) and if found, replace the one in `$result` with the one from `$temp`. I tried using `ReplaceChild()`, but that seems not to work, perhaps a PowerShell 2.0 issue.

So, with those two bits of data, is there a better way to revise the XML, and is there a way to make it work with a function that properly passes the XML by value? FWIW, I am refactoring to avoid the global XML variable I had been using successfully. I generally don't like global variables, but perhaps this is one situation where I just have to use them?

**EDIT:**
So, trying to isolate the issue, and running into new issues. Here I am trying to create two XML variables in the function, replace a node from one variable with the node from another and pass it back out of the function, then write to console to verify the result is correct (the difference is SilentModeID should be 9). Problem is the two here strings aren't working. Tried with single quotes as well, but still throwing errors. Not really apples to apples as in my real code I am not using here strings, I am reading the XML from files, but for the purposes of discussion it seemed the better way to go. So, first new question, what the heck am I doing wrong with the here strings? Once that's working we can see if passing the XML back out is broken the same way.

```
function Write-PxXmlToConsole ($xml) {
    $stringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $xmlWriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter $stringWriter
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented"
    $xml.WriteTo($xmlWriter)
    $xmlWriter.Flush()
    $stringWriter.Flush()
    Write-Host $stringWriter.ToString()
}


function Import-PxXml {

$result = @{
    success = $true
    xml = $null
    log = $null
}

[xml]$assets = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Definitions>
<InstallTypes>
<InstallType id="deployment">
<SilentModeID>1</SilentModeID>
</InstallTypes>
</InstallType>
</Definitions>
"@

[xml]$newAssets = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Definitions>
<InstallTypes>
<InstallType id="deployment">
<SilentModeID>9</SilentModeID>
</InstallType>
</InstallTypes>
</Definitions>
"@

$nodeName = 'deployment'

$oldnode = $assets.selectSingleNode("/Definitions/InstallTypes/InstallType[@id='$nodeName']")
$newnode = $newAssets.selectSingleNode("/Definitions/InstallTypes/InstallType[@id='$nodeName']")
$importNode = $assets.ImportNode($newnode, $true)

$oldnode.ParentNode.AppendChild($importNode)
$oldnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild($oldnode)

$result.xml = $assets
$result.log = 'Crossed Fingers'

return $result
}


$test = Import-PxXml
Write-PxXmlToConsole $test.xml
```

Comment: "either of those last two lines is what causes the $return hash to blow up" In what way?

Comment: It gives the appearance of a corrupt pipeline issue. If I iterate through $return at the end of the function it looks "right", but iterating through the variable that receives the function I get what seems to be a single key, with no name, and no value, but with a .count of 3 keys, not the four keys that are in the $return hash in the function. Rem those two lines in the function and everything works in the calling code. But of course the XML isn't changed, so it isn't useful code, just "working" code.

Comment: There is a bunch of other code, so I am trying to isolate the  problem enough to post a useful example without hundreds of extraneous lines. But that in itself is taking a bunch of time.

Comment: And why exactly is the phrase "Any insight greatly appreciated" somehow forbidden?

Comment: @Gordon That phrase is not really forbidden, but this kind of "fluff" is a bit frowned upon on SO because it does not add anything of substance to the question. *Of course* you welcome any insight, that's why you've asked the question. The same goes for signing your question or writing a short bio at the top, as people often feel the need to do. Resist the urge for small-talk and concentrate on the raw facts.

Comment: PowerShell has a tendency to convert types on the fly as it seems fit. I  would try to explicitly declare $test as [xml]$test and see if that makes any difference. Or first inspect the type of $test after it received the function result to see what it has become. You may also want to be explicit about the intermediate results, declaring variables with a [System.Xml.XmlElement] prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RemoveChild()` and `AppendChild()` method returns the child node in question, polluting your output.

Suppress the output and you'll be fine:

```
$null = $oldnode.ParentNode.AppendChild($importNode)
$null = $oldnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild($oldnode)
```

Comment: Oh, huzzah! Polluted pipeline after all! Sometimes I really wish there was a way to blanket opt out of pipeline behavior, then opt back in when needed. In the meantime, thanks for the redirect! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I long for a strict `return` as well now and again, but you can't have everything :)

Comment: True Dat. And really the issue was I forgot
First Rule of PowerShell: It's probably Pipeline Pollution
From now on, if I have an issue and I can isolate it to a line, my first troubleshooting step is to throw an > $null on the end and see what happens.

Comment: If you can use `return` to specify what to output, you could just as well save every function/cmdlet output to a variable or `$null`. The extra words won't break your hard drive. :-)